# Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory and FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices' on running a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart, flutter-dependencies

when I do `flutter run`:
..\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app_demo>flutter run
Following is the error I get:
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  **Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()**.

  > **Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter()**.

I'm working on the VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was also facing the same problem searched a lot but found no answer for this problem so what i did was to make a new project and transferring all the dart file one by one by copy-pasting it was a bit time-consuming though but it worked so you can try it too